# permission for restricted folder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I restricted access to a folder with htaccess, and there is a mp3 file in this folder. When flash mp3 player try to load mp3 in this folder, it cant. is there a way to give permission to flash player ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know whether Flash can do basic authentication. Try `username:password@domain.com/directory/mp3file.mp3` as the URL, but no guarantees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no you can't. Both the browser (when directly trying to access the mp3 files) and the flash player works on the client side, and makes exactly the same kind of requests to the server to retrieve the mp3.

If you can modify the flash file, you could embed the mp3s into the flash file, that way clients won't have direct access to it.

Comment: flash gets mp3 path from a php file with xml headers. so what if i provide mp3 path like this username:pass@domain.com/path/file.mp3 ?

Comment: Yes, it will keep out the casual users. But don't consider this to be a security solution ... that username AND the password will be transmitted from client to server (from flash to php). Even if you use a secure line for it, hacks made on the client side can leak out your username and password (because the client knows what is being sent). Even worse, this can be very sensitive if the same password can be used to gain access to other parts of your server. Any hacker would have a field day!